# 7Zip - Command Line : Exclude folder(s) by wildcard pattern?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

Any idea how to exclude a wild-carded path(s) from a command-line 7zip command?

I'm doing something like this:

```
7z.exe a -t7z archive.7z FolderToArchive\ -mx0
```

and would like to exclude any `\bin\*.*` or `\obj\*.*` folders found underneath "FolderToArchive".

To exclude files, you can use the `-x` parameter. The help file gives this example for using `-x`:

```
7z a -tzip archive.zip *.txt -x!temp.*
```

That's great for excluding a file. But, again, I would like to exclude a wildcard-specified folder. Under my "FolderToArchive" there are multiple folders, under those folders there may or may not be `bin\` and `obj\` folders. I would like to not include these in the archive.

I've tried patterns like

```
-x!bin\*
-x!bin\*.*
-x!\bin\*
-x!\bin\*.*
-x!\\bin\\*
-x!\\bin\\*.*
```

None seem to exclude the `bin\` folder. Is this simply a limitation of 7zip?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

To exclude the *bin* and *obj* folders recursively you can use the command:

```
7z.exe a -t7z archive.7z FolderToArchive\ -mx0 -xr!bin -xr!obj
```

Comment: For everyone else: if you want to ignore only the files in the root directory, use `-xr0!*.zip` - at least I couldn't get it to work without the `r0`.

Comment: Also, if this is in a Linux/Unix command line, you may need to enclose in single quotes, to not add pre-processing by the shell, e.g. `'-x!$RECYCLE.BIN'` to exclude the Recycle bin of an external drive.

Comment: what is -mx0 good for?

Comment: What does -mx0 mean, and what is the ! after -x mean?

Comment: Windows batch files with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` require the `!` to be escaped with `^`  like `-xr^^!skip_this_dir`

Comment: On Linux you need to quote the `!`: `-xr'!bin'` (NOT the `-xr` bit)

Comment: @ESP32 -mx0 is a 7Zip Switch.

    -m = set compression method,
    -x0 = compression level,

    where by the compression scale is from 0 to 9.

    0 = copy without compression (which is the lowest) and
    9 = ultra compression (which is the highest) Ref: https://www.scottklement.com/p7zip/MANUAL/switches/method.htm

Answer (score 29):

To avoid bug, use -r or -xr carefully.

suppose you have directories like:

```
.\path1\path2\bin
.\path1\path2\src
.\path3\path4\path5\bin
.\path3\path4\path5\src
```

and run the command:

```
7z a -t7z archive.7z .\path1\path2 .\path3\path4\path5 -xr!bin
```

what you got in archive.7z:

```
.\path2\src
.\path5\src
```

That is, the `.\path2\` and `.\path5\` became the **top folder** in archive.7z, and both `bin` directories were excluded.

-x only support path/filename **relative** to the top folder in archive.

So, if you only want to exclude `.\path1\path2\bin`, but to include all the other 'bin' directories, the command should be like this:

```
7z a -t7z archive.7z .\path1\path2 .\path3\path4\path5 -x!path2\bin
```

I tried to use absolute path in -x, but never succeed.

---

**Update:**

There is an option `-spf` in 7z for Linux which works with absolute path.

According to [Marco](https://superuser.com/a/1063209/304204), `-spf` is also available on Windows from 7-zip 15.14

Comment: Note: At least on Ubuntu you are best advised to put all those -x terms in single quotes `'-x!path2\bin'` to not run into shell substitution... (getting you a much longer, syntactically incorrect “command”...)

Comment: To refer to @FrankNocke 's comment, you can also do this on windows to allow dots in folder names: `'-xr!\.foo'`

Answer (score 2):

Based on @zhazha's answer and make it more clear about how to exclude sub folders exactly. On Windows 10, to backup a Visual Studio solution root folder:

```
D:\VS2019\Sln1
```

then:

```
//goto the parent of the root folder first which make thing clearer
//not sure what will happen if you go into the root folder
cd D:\VS2019
"<path-of-7z>\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx0 Sln1_backup.zip Sln1 -x!Sln1\.vs -x!Sln1\Debug -x!Sln1\Release -x!Sln1\lib -x!Sln1\Project1\x64 -x!Sln1\Project2\obj
```

Then you can be sure only the specified sub folders are excluded, for example Sln1\Project3\obj or Sln1\Project4\lib will not be excluded unintentionally. Works for the hidden huge .vs folder.

-mx0 means archive/no compression.