# 7-zip backup folders, exclude some of folders but keep excluded folder's name

Tags: linux, backup, 7-zip

By using 7-zip in Linux I need to

- save zip file to absolute path: `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/myfiles.7z`
- backup all files and subfolders inside this: `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/`
- exclude these folders', its subfolders and all files inside them totally: `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/tmp/sessions/`
  `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/posts/`
- excludes all the files inside these folders, but keep the folder names:
  `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/news/`
  `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/handy/`
  I mean, zip file will have "news" and "handy" folders, but the folder will be empty

I tried this but didn't help:

```
# 7za a 
  /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/myfiles.7z 
  /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/ 
   -xr!app\tmp\sessions\ 
   -xr!app\posts\ 
   -xr!app\news\*.* 
   -xr!app\handy\*.*
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding "`*`" before the exclude expression (and using forward-slashes, this is Linux, right?) helps here:

```
$ 7za a /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/webroot/myfiles.7z  \
    /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/ \
    -xr\!*app/tmp/sessions \
    -xr\!*app/posts \
    -xr\!*app/news/* \
    -xr\!*app/handy/*
```

There's also [7Zip - Command Line : Exclude folder(s) by wildcard pattern?](https://superuser.com/questions/97342/7zip-command-line-exclude-folders-by-wildcard-pattern)

Comment: This worked for me -- 7-Zip [64] 9.20 on Ubuntu 16.04.