# 7zip exclude folder by pattern in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

I'm trying to achieve this but using 7z from linux command line:

```
zip -r target.zip source_folder -x *.git* -x *node_modules/\*
```

I tried with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/97342/7zip-command-line-exclude-folders-by-wildcard-pattern) but I get the following error:

```
$ 7z a mtss.7z mtss-ws -xr0!*.git -xr0!node_modules
bash: !node_modules: event not found
```

Any ideas? I though it was going to be easy...

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a special character to bash, it is used to refer to previous commands (see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found) on ServerFault).

Try:

```
set +H
```

to disable this functionality and then your command:

```
7z a mtss.7z mtss-ws -xr0!*.git -xr0!node_modules
```

and then:

```
set -H
```

to restore bash settings.