# 7-zip - Looking to zip sub folders but not all sub folders

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have a folder structure of:

```
-MAIN
-- Branches
---001
---002
---003
```

I want to zip 003 up so I have a zip of

```
-MAIN
--Branches
---003
```

I'm using:

```
7z a "C:\My Files.zip" "C:\MAIN\Branches\003"
```

But this gives me a folder of just `003` in My Zip without the folders before it.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is expected. you added only that folder. you need to start from top and exclude all what you don't want - [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/97342/7zip-command-line-exclude-folders-by-wildcard-pattern)

Comment: I'm struggling to see if I can apply that logic, I use a variable of %branch% to identify 001 / 002 / 003.

I'm not sure how i'd exclude the folders i didn't want without explicitly calling them out.

Comment: unfortunately yes, you will need to specify them, I suggest you make two files eg. exclude.txt and include.txt and call 7zip with the @filename for include and exclude parameters