# Exclude all folders containing "discarded" with 7z

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, 7-zip, exclude

When I do

```
7z a test.zip -x!*discarded* test
```

with

```
test/
test/a.txt
test/subfolder/
test/subfolder/a.txt
test/subfolder/discarded/
test/subfolder/discarded/a.txt
test/subfolder2/a.txt
test/subfolder2/subfolder3/a.txt
test/subfolder2/subfolder3/discarded/
test/subfolder2/subfolder3/discarded/a.txt
```

then, unfortunately, everything is still included!

**How to exclude every file/folder like `*/discarded/*`?** (or, alternatively, exclude any file/folder whose absolute path contains `discarded`?)

Also, how to exclude all files ending by `.txt`? (`-x!*.txt` doesn't work)

I use 7z on Windows.

Note: [7Zip - Command Line : Exclude folder(s) by wildcard pattern?](https://superuser.com/questions/97342/7zip-command-line-exclude-folders-by-wildcard-pattern) didn't help here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski In my case, the shell is Windows. I was looking for a crossplatform way, since I use 7z both from Win and Linux, but for simplicity, my need here is first for Windows.

Comment: According to your linked ticket, it should be `7z a test.zip test -xr!discarded`. That did not work?

Comment: @LPChip I did a new test, and I confirm it works now. I don't know what happened.

Comment: I thought that looked correct. Glad it worked now. Maybe you did not write the r for recursive? -x!... would not work, but -xr!... would match the word and exclude it recursively.

Comment: Might be nice to credit @LPChip in your answer

Comment: @SandeepBansal Yes of course, I always do it in such cases, I forgot here! Fixed now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a new test, as [suggested by LPChip](https://superuser.com/questions/1833280/exclude-all-folders-containing-discarded-with-7z?noredirect=1#comment2892755_1833280), this works:

```
7z a test.zip -xr!discarded -xr!*.txt test
```